# Debian - How to prevent file corruption on power loss?

Tags: debian, systemd, systemctl, corruption

I have a Debian based OS, and I am creating a program that have support for upgrading itself. The program is ran on system-level as a systemd service.

I have a problem when I update the software, which in practice means replacing some files on `/opt/myApp/` folder (home of all my application code) and replacing systemd service unit file `/etc/systemd/system/my_service.service`. After this I run `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl enable my_service` and `systemctl restart` which works as intended. How ever, if a sudden power loss happens right after this, the new files copied to `/opt/myApp/` and the new service file goes to size 0 in the filesystem, which of course then causes my program to fail and the service to go into masked state. If I reboot my system after the installation, the "danger" goes away and the system can handle sudden power losses without effect on the files I care about.

Is this some kind of file system corruption problem? How could I prevent this problem without rebooting the system? What could be the root of this issue?

Comment: Call `sync` to write buffers to disk?

Comment: @vidarlo As a pretty new linux developer I didn't even know that files created doesn't immediately go to persistent storage. Thanks, that worked. I think there is no way to make comment a solve to a question?

Comment: All modern operating systems have write buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [.deb packaging](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging) your software. This way, [dpkg](https://wiki.debian.org/dpkg) will handle this issue as well as the entire update process including the application files & the SystemD service unit. If something goes wrong, e.g., a sudden power loss or other interruption, dpkg will be aware of the situation and suggest the necessary action, which might be a re-installation of the package or `dpkg --configure -a`.